# Slim ignoring class & style on f.select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm sure I'm being blind, can you spot something I've missed:

```
= f.select :region, options_for_select(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/regions.yml").collect{|x| [x[1]['name'], x[0]]}), class: "form-control", style: 'display:none;'
```

Slim just ignores the class & style statements, but everything else looks fine. What am I doing wrong? (rails 4).

Comment: Try putting them in a `{}`.

Comment: Tried that, no difference.

Comment: Ok try this `= f.select :region, options_for_select(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/regions.yml").collect{|x| [x[1]['name'], x[0]]}), {}, {class: "form-control", style: 'display:none;'}`

Comment: That worked! What's the extra {} a placeholder for? I don't see it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {},
>   &block) public

If you look into your code,

```
= f.select :region, options_for_select(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/regions.yml").collect{|x| [x[1]['name'], x[0]]}), class: "form-control", style: 'display:none;'
```

***class*** and ***style*** should be in a place of `html_options = {}` but currently they are in `options = {}`, so they are discarded.

The below works

```
= f.select :region, options_for_select(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/regions.yml").collect{|x‌​| [x[1]['name'], x[0]]}), {}, {class: "form-control", style: 'display:none;'}
```